# possible to change one variable or another inside of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I don't know if this is possible so I figured this would be the place to ask.

I have two inputs and they each hold a unique value. They each have their own respective variable that the value is saved into. I was wondering if there was a way to use just one function to update their values instead of two seperate ones. Below is my code so far.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="valueOne" onchange="changeValueOne(this.value)">
    <input type="text" id="valueTwo" onchange="changeValueTwo(this.value)">
</form>


var valueOne = parseFloat($('#valueOne'));
var valueTwo = parseFloat($('#valueTwo'));

function changeValueOne(newValueOne) {
    valueOne = newValueOne;
}
function changeValueTwo(newValueTwo) {
    valueTwo = newValueTwo;
}
```

Comment: Your `parseFloat` invocation doesn't seem to make much sense as you're calling it on the input elements, not on their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var valueOne, valueTwo;

$("#valueOne, #valueTwo").change(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'valueOne') {
        valueOne = $(this).val();
    } else {
        valueTwo = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

Comment: Good answer. I'd use triple equals in your comparison just to be on the safe side.

Comment: that won't change the global variables, just define new local ones that get instantly discarded.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a second parameter to indicate which variable to store and/or where.

```
var values;
function changeValue(newValue, pos){
   values[pos] = newValue;
}
```

Change html to:

```
 <input type="text" id="valueOne" onchange="changeValue(this.value, 'first')">
 <input type="text" id="valueOne" onchange="changeValue(this.value, 'second')">
```

Alternatively if you want to store them in separate variables:

```
function changeValue(newValue, pos){
   if(pos == 'first'){
      valueOne = newValue;
   } else if(pos == 'second'){
      valueTwo = newValue;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple expandable way uses a collection instead of vars:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="valueOne" onchange="changeValue(value, id)">  
    <input type="text" id="valueTwo" onchange="changeValue(value, id)">
</form>

<script>
var vals={ 
    valueOne : parseFloat($('#valueOne').val()),
    valueTwo : parseFloat($('#valueTwo').val())
};

function changeValue(newValue, slot) {
    vals[slot] = newValue;
}

</script>
```

not only is it incredibly simple and fast, this lets you add many options without reworking the forking code (`if`s), all you need to do is modify the `vals` object and the handler will keep up automatically with all available options, even creating new ones on-the-fly if needed (from new inputs being appended during run-time).